# Something Went Wrong - Google Wallet API Pass Creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-wallet

I'm following the guide here: https://developers.google.com/wallet/generic/web?authuser=2 to setup my Google Wallet Pass Generic passes.

I have generated the following payload for my JWT, however every time I try to test it in Google Wallet, I see the following error:

[image]

This is my decoded JWT:

```
{
  "iss": "xxxxx@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "aud": "google",
  "origins": [
    "www.xxx.com"
  ],
  "typ": "savetowallet",
  "payload": {
    "genericClasses": [
      {
        "id": "<issuer_id>.<random_text>",
        "classTemplateInfo": {
          "cardTemplateOverride": {
            "cardRowTemplateInfos": [
              {
                "twoItems": {
                  "startItem": {
                    "firstValue": {
                      "fields": [
                        {
                          "fieldPath": "object.textModulesData['purchased_lattes']"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "endItem": {
                    "firstValue": {
                      "fields": [
                        {
                          "fieldPath": "object.textModulesData['remaining_lattes']"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "twoItems": {
                  "startItem": {
                    "firstValue": {
                      "fields": [
                        {
                          "fieldPath": "object.textModulesData['available_lattes']"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "endItem": {
                    "firstValue": {
                      "fields": [
                        {
                          "fieldPath": "object.textModulesData['free_lattes_received']"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "genericObjects": [
      {
        "id": "<issuer_id>.a372e87e-4347-4e7b-b326-f2e7fb649367",
        "classId": "<issuer_id>.<same_random_text>",
        "logo": {
          "sourceUri": {
            "uri": "<png_url>"
          },
          "contentDescription": {
            "defaultValue": {
              "language": "en",
              "value": ""
            }
          }
        },
        "cardTitle": {
          "defaultValue": {
            "language": "en",
            "value": "xxxx"
          }
        },
        "subheader": {
          "defaultValue": {
            "language": "en",
            "value": "xxxxx"
          }
        },
        "header": {
          "defaultValue": {
            "language": "en",
            "value": "xxxx"
          }
        },
        "textModulesData": [
          {
            "id": "purchased_lattes",
            "header": "Purchased Lattes",
            "body": "0"
          },
          {
            "id": "remaining_lattes",
            "header": "Remaining Lattes",
            "body": "5"
          },
          {
            "id": "available_lattes",
            "header": "Available Lattes",
            "body": "0"
          },
          {
            "id": "free_lattes_received",
            "header": "Free Lattes Received!",
            "body": "0"
          }
        ],
        "barcode": {
          "type": "QR_CODE",
          "value": "<some_url>",
          "alternateText": "a372e87e-4347-4e7b-b"
        },
        "hexBackgroundColor": "#0d7787",
        "heroImage": {
          "sourceUri": {
            "uri": "<some_url>"
          },
          "contentDescription": {
            "defaultValue": {
              "language": "en",
              "value": "HERO_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "iat": 1680012899
}
```

I have reached out to Google Wallet Support, however they haven't given me any useful feedback yet.

I also tried using the "Validate" functionality on the Google Wallet site, however it fails without any specific error.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to dynamically create google-wallet pass with Golang, and I end up on the same issue as you. One thing to note tho, is that the lenght of the JWT should be max 1800 chars. I have no idea how we are supposed to achieve that, at best I got 2432.

Comment: @JayCee Did that worked for you with 2432 chars ? when i load my JWT link over android browser it launches the wallet app but shows something went wrong. I'm using the google-walletobjects_20230711-java to generate the pass. I don't want the my classes to be created on the google console and add them in the code. Any help or suggestion?

Comment: Yes it's a pain, the way I found is that a lot of fields are actually not necessary and can be removed for a simple google pass. But if you want something complexe with a lot of personalisation, you'll have to create the base model on the console. I don't understand why they build it this way tbh, it kinda dumb

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to have mine working. Few things I had to make sure of:

You're using the private key of the account passed within `"iss"`, make sure your payload is small.

Here what my JWT looks like:

```
{
  "aud": "google",
  "iss": "xxxx-android-wallet@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "origins": [
    "localhost"
  ],
  "payload": {
    "genericClasses": [
      {
        "id": "3388XXXXXX88.NameOfClass"
      }
    ],
    "genericObjects": [
      {
        "id": "3388XXXXXX88.<object_id>",
        "classId": "3388XXXXXX88.NameOfClass"
      }
    ]
  },
  "typ": "savetowallet"
}
```

tbh I don't think I even need the `genericClasses` object in the payload.

Otherwise the info to generate your JWT are correct, I personally didn't put the `iat`.

I hope that helps!

Edit: I tried and can confirm you don't need the `"genericClasses"` in your payload.

Comment: Where should the "classTemplateInfo" belongs to "genericClasses" be?
I've created a Class in Google Wallet & Pay Console, but I can't find this info where to set it. "textModulesData" of the pass that has been added to a user's Wallet disappears, and I strongly believe the root cause is missed"classTemplateInfo". What should I do about this?

Comment: I've figured out a way of updating "classTemplateInfo" belongs to "genericClasses".
Just ignore my comment. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using GenericPrivatePass to generate pass for google wallet and my jwt token goes beyond 1800 chars. I saw there is an option to create the class and its metadata from wallet api console, but will that work when it goes to production ? My pass data is dynamic which comes from API. How do i achieve this ?

Comment: @Madhu on the console you only want to create the base of your template (you don't have a choice, a template has to be created on the console). Then you can generate dynamically the pass on your API (that's what I do, a pass personalised to a user). But the generation of the jwt is exactly as my code shows in this post. Saving a lot of characters for the JWT

Comment: I think this is applicable only for the generic and other passes type, but for private passes we cannot create a template and use the class id in the code. For Private passes GenericPrivatePasses has to be create programmatically using their libraries.

Comment: I was able to solve this for my private passes with these steps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77282559/getting-something-went-wrong-when-added-google-private-passes