# Unable to see the additional text fields in my generic google wallet pass

Tags: google-wallet

i am trying to generate generic google wallet pass. i have been able to do that successfully but the issue i have is that i am unable to see the text fields that i override in cardTemplateOverride object. These are 'contacts' and 'points' fields. Attaching the code for reference.

````
async function createPassClass(req, res) {
  // TODO: Create a Generic pass class
  let genericClass = {
    'id': `${classId}`,
    'classTemplateInfo': {
      'cardTemplateOverride': {
        'cardRowTemplateInfos': [
          {
            'twoItems': {
              'startItem': {
                'firstValue': {
                  'fields': [
                    {
                      'fieldPath': 'object.textModulesData["points"]'
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              'endItem': {
                'firstValue': {
                  'fields': [
                    {
                      'fieldPath': 'object.textModulesData["contacts"]'
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    },
  };
}

async function createPassObject(req, res) {
  // TODO: Create a new Generic pass for the user
  let objectSuffix = `${req.body.email.replace(/[^\w.-]/g, '_')}`;
  let objectId = `${issuerId}.${objectSuffix}`;

  let genericObject = {
    'cardTitle': {
      'defaultValue': {
        'language': 'en',
        'value': 'Google I/O \'22'
      }
    },
    
    'textModulesData': [
      {
        'header': 'POINTS',
        'body': '1234',
        'id': 'points'
      },
      {
        'header': 'CONTACTS',
        'body': '20',
        'id': 'contacts'
      }
    ]
  };
}
;```


This is the exact code given in google codelab and it's not working as expected like it should show the Contacts and Points fields on the pass but it isn't.
````

Comment: facing the same issue here... Points and contacts are shown on the detailScreen. But not showing it after saving pass on front screen along with QR code screen

Answer (score 0):

Yes even i had same issues. but i tried generic class and object from here [Something Went Wrong - Google Wallet API Pass Creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75867483/something-went-wrong-google-wallet-api-pass-creation)

they did work, and i modified according to my code. i believe its because of the quotes

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference your class into your object.

```
'id': `${objectId}`,
'classId': `${issuerId}.${classSuffix}`,
'genericType': 'GENERIC_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED',
```