# Getting something went wrong when added google private passes

Tags: react-native, jwt, google-pay, android-pay, wallet

I'm getting an error after loading the genericprivate passes jwtlink from android app using below code.

```
Linking.openURL(jwtlink)
```

On the click on Add to Google Wallet button action, i'm opening the link using linking library and it launches google wallet app and shows "Something went wrong". Even tried with demo test users added under test account in google wallet api console.

I have shared the same jwt token with google wallet support team and one their member able to add the pass on to his wallet app after clicking on the jwtlink.

What might be reason that i'm getting "Something went wrong" error when trying to add the pass over wallet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Private Passes which are in demo mode and to test those pass it requires individual testers personal gmail accounts to be added under Test accounts in google wallet api console.
2. The email account which has access to google wallet api console has to have admin access.
3. The client email which gets generated from google cloud service account, that email has to be added as developer under the users tab in google wallet api console.

By doing all the above things, i was able to solve the "something went wrong" error while opening the JWT link over android browser.

Comment: very well summarized!